# MySQL Spatial: Is it possible to ignore results with "Inconsistent intersection points"?

Tags: mysql, spatial

I have a MySQL database with geolocations and I'd like to get the ST_INTERSECTION result from the intersecting polygons and a given polygon.

I need the ST_INTERSECTION result to measure if the resulting polygon is at least 50 % inside the given polygon.

The problem is that some of the results will cause an "Inconsistent intersection points" error.

Is it possible to ignore those results or validate that the ST_INTERSECTION will work before it crashes?

[image]

EDIT: The 2 polygons, which produce the error:

```
SELECT
ST_INTERSECTION(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[18.04682, 59.33574000000001], [18.0473, 59.33566], [18.04773, 59.3355], [18.05032, 59.33467], [18.05202, 59.33382000000001], [18.05403, 59.33475], [18.05554, 59.3351], [18.05601, 59.33522], [18.05601, 59.33522], [18.05605, 59.33523], [18.05605, 59.33523], [18.05886, 59.33592999999999], [18.05882, 59.33598], [18.05882, 59.33598], [18.0588, 59.336000000000006], [18.0588, 59.336000000000006], [18.05796, 59.33699], [18.05689, 59.3367], [18.05605, 59.33648000000001], [18.05605, 59.33648000000001], [18.05601, 59.336470000000006], [18.05601, 59.336470000000006], [18.05502, 59.33621000000001], [18.05457, 59.33666], [18.05397, 59.33728], [18.05354, 59.3377], [18.05311, 59.33758999999999], [18.05456, 59.336000000000006], [18.05456, 59.336000000000006], [18.05458, 59.33598], [18.05458, 59.33598], [18.05476, 59.33578], [18.05337, 59.33547000000001], [18.05122, 59.33592999999999], [18.05056, 59.33598], [18.05048, 59.336000000000006], [18.05048, 59.336000000000006], [18.05011, 59.33610999999999], [18.05056, 59.33622999999999], [18.05056, 59.33622999999999], [18.05112, 59.33637], [18.05056, 59.33698], [18.04831, 59.33631], [18.04803, 59.33635], [18.04734, 59.336000000000006], [18.04734, 59.336000000000006], [18.0473, 59.33598], [18.0473, 59.33598], [18.04682, 59.33574000000001]]]}'),
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[18.05202, 59.33382000000001], [18.05287, 59.3332], [18.05287, 59.3332], [18.0529, 59.33318], [18.05289, 59.33318], [18.05294, 59.33315], [18.05427, 59.333549999999995], [18.05463, 59.3332], [18.05463, 59.3332], [18.05465, 59.33318], [18.05465, 59.33318], [18.05479, 59.33305000000001], [18.05453, 59.33297999999999], [18.0564, 59.33088], [18.05775, 59.33123], [18.0585, 59.3304], [18.0585, 59.3304], [18.05942, 59.32939], [18.06056, 59.32976], [18.06, 59.3304], [18.06, 59.3304], [18.05811, 59.33253], [18.05752, 59.33318], [18.05752, 59.33318], [18.05751, 59.33319], [18.0583, 59.333400000000005], [18.05897, 59.33356], [18.06011, 59.33388000000001], [18.0615, 59.33424999999999], [18.06129, 59.33448], [18.06051, 59.33427], [18.05736, 59.33347], [18.05697, 59.33380999999999], [18.05667, 59.33373], [18.05657, 59.33382000000001], [18.05665, 59.33385], [18.0559, 59.33466], [18.05444, 59.33432], [18.05431, 59.33449], [18.05577, 59.33485], [18.05554, 59.3351], [18.05403, 59.33475], [18.05202, 59.33382000000001]]]}')
)

SELECT
ST_INTERSECTION(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[18.04682, 59.33574000000001], [18.0473, 59.33566], [18.04773, 59.3355], [18.05032, 59.33467], [18.05202, 59.33382000000001], [18.05403, 59.33475], [18.05554, 59.3351], [18.05601, 59.33522], [18.05601, 59.33522], [18.05605, 59.33523], [18.05605, 59.33523], [18.05886, 59.33592999999999], [18.05882, 59.33598], [18.05882, 59.33598], [18.0588, 59.336000000000006], [18.0588, 59.336000000000006], [18.05796, 59.33699], [18.05689, 59.3367], [18.05605, 59.33648000000001], [18.05605, 59.33648000000001], [18.05601, 59.336470000000006], [18.05601, 59.336470000000006], [18.05502, 59.33621000000001], [18.05457, 59.33666], [18.05397, 59.33728], [18.05354, 59.3377], [18.05311, 59.33758999999999], [18.05456, 59.336000000000006], [18.05456, 59.336000000000006], [18.05458, 59.33598], [18.05458, 59.33598], [18.05476, 59.33578], [18.05337, 59.33547000000001], [18.05122, 59.33592999999999], [18.05056, 59.33598], [18.05048, 59.336000000000006], [18.05048, 59.336000000000006], [18.05011, 59.33610999999999], [18.05056, 59.33622999999999], [18.05056, 59.33622999999999], [18.05112, 59.33637], [18.05056, 59.33698], [18.04831, 59.33631], [18.04803, 59.33635], [18.04734, 59.336000000000006], [18.04734, 59.336000000000006], [18.0473, 59.33598], [18.0473, 59.33598], [18.04682, 59.33574000000001]]]}'),
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[18.05202, 59.33382000000001], [18.05287, 59.3332], [18.05287, 59.3332], [18.0529, 59.33318], [18.05289, 59.33318], [18.05294, 59.33315], [18.05427, 59.333549999999995], [18.05463, 59.3332], [18.05463, 59.3332], [18.05465, 59.33318], [18.05465, 59.33318], [18.05479, 59.33305000000001], [18.05453, 59.33297999999999], [18.0564, 59.33088], [18.05775, 59.33123], [18.0585, 59.3304], [18.0585, 59.3304], [18.05942, 59.32939], [18.06056, 59.32976], [18.06, 59.3304], [18.06, 59.3304], [18.05811, 59.33253], [18.05752, 59.33318], [18.05752, 59.33318], [18.05751, 59.33319], [18.0583, 59.333400000000005], [18.05897, 59.33356], [18.06011, 59.33388000000001], [18.0615, 59.33424999999999], [18.06129, 59.33448], [18.06051, 59.33427], [18.05736, 59.33347], [18.05697, 59.33380999999999], [18.05667, 59.33373], [18.05657, 59.33382000000001], [18.05665, 59.33385], [18.0559, 59.33466], [18.05444, 59.33432], [18.05431, 59.33449], [18.05577, 59.33485], [18.05554, 59.3351], [18.05403, 59.33475], [18.05202, 59.33382000000001]]]}')
)
```

Comment: A [mre] which shows this problem would be nice.

Comment: Here I have a sample of 2 polygons that will get this error:

https://pastebin.com/8VCcW2en

Comment: I (and not just I) do not like external site, so I added them to the question.

Comment: Thank you Luuk :)

Comment: Could you please add more information on the production environment (mysql version, compiler, OS, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I tried some thing with this statement (the second one you provided):

```
SELECT
ST_INTERSECTION(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[18.04682, 59.33574000000001], [18.0473, 59.33566], [18.04773, 59.3355], [18.05032, 59.33467], [18.05202, 59.33382000000001], [18.05403, 59.33475], [18.05554, 59.3351], [18.05601, 59.33522], [18.05601, 59.33522], [18.05605, 59.33523], [18.05605, 59.33523], [18.05886, 59.33592999999999], [18.05882, 59.33598], [18.05882, 59.33598], [18.0588, 59.336000000000006], [18.0588, 59.336000000000006], [18.05796, 59.33699], [18.05689, 59.3367], [18.05605, 59.33648000000001], [18.05605, 59.33648000000001], [18.05601, 59.336470000000006], [18.05601, 59.336470000000006], [18.05502, 59.33621000000001], [18.05457, 59.33666], [18.05397, 59.33728], [18.05354, 59.3377], [18.05311, 59.33758999999999], [18.05456, 59.336000000000006], [18.05456, 59.336000000000006], [18.05458, 59.33598], [18.05458, 59.33598], [18.05476, 59.33578], [18.05337, 59.33547000000001], [18.05122, 59.33592999999999], [18.05056, 59.33598], [18.05048, 59.336000000000006], [18.05048, 59.336000000000006], [18.05011, 59.33610999999999], [18.05056, 59.33622999999999], [18.05056, 59.33622999999999], [18.05112, 59.33637], [18.05056, 59.33698], [18.04831, 59.33631], [18.04803, 59.33635], [18.04734, 59.336000000000006], [18.04734, 59.336000000000006], [18.0473, 59.33598], [18.0473, 59.33598], [18.04682, 59.33574000000001]]]}'),
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[18.05202, 59.33382000000001], [18.05287, 59.3332], [18.05287, 59.3332], [18.0529, 59.33318], [18.05289, 59.33318], [18.05294, 59.33315], [18.05427, 59.333549999999995], [18.05463, 59.3332], [18.05463, 59.3332], [18.05465, 59.33318], [18.05465, 59.33318], [18.05479, 59.33305000000001], [18.05453, 59.33297999999999], [18.0564, 59.33088], [18.05775, 59.33123], [18.0585, 59.3304], [18.0585, 59.3304], [18.05942, 59.32939], [18.06056, 59.32976], [18.06, 59.3304], [18.06, 59.3304], [18.05811, 59.33253], [18.05752, 59.33318], [18.05752, 59.33318], [18.05751, 59.33319], [18.0583, 59.333400000000005], [18.05897, 59.33356], [18.06011, 59.33388000000001], [18.0615, 59.33424999999999], [18.06129, 59.33448], [18.06051, 59.33427], [18.05736, 59.33347], [18.05697, 59.33380999999999], [18.05667, 59.33373], [18.05657, 59.33382000000001], [18.05665, 59.33385], [18.0559, 59.33466], [18.05444, 59.33432], [18.05431, 59.33449], [18.05577, 59.33485], [18.05554, 59.3351], [18.05403, 59.33475], [18.05202, 59.33382000000001]]]}')
);
```

When adding `ST_GeomFromText(ST_ASTEXT(......))` (two times):

```
SELECT
ST_INTERSECTION(
    ST_GeomFromText(ST_ASTEXT(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[18.04682, 59.33574000000001], [18.0473, 59.33566], [18.04773, 59.3355], [18.05032, 59.33467], [18.05202, 59.33382000000001], [18.05403, 59.33475], [18.05554, 59.3351], [18.05601, 59.33522], [18.05601, 59.33522], [18.05605, 59.33523], [18.05605, 59.33523], [18.05886, 59.33592999999999], [18.05882, 59.33598], [18.05882, 59.33598], [18.0588, 59.336000000000006], [18.0588, 59.336000000000006], [18.05796, 59.33699], [18.05689, 59.3367], [18.05605, 59.33648000000001], [18.05605, 59.33648000000001], [18.05601, 59.336470000000006], [18.05601, 59.336470000000006], [18.05502, 59.33621000000001], [18.05457, 59.33666], [18.05397, 59.33728], [18.05354, 59.3377], [18.05311, 59.33758999999999], [18.05456, 59.336000000000006], [18.05456, 59.336000000000006], [18.05458, 59.33598], [18.05458, 59.33598], [18.05476, 59.33578], [18.05337, 59.33547000000001], [18.05122, 59.33592999999999], [18.05056, 59.33598], [18.05048, 59.336000000000006], [18.05048, 59.336000000000006], [18.05011, 59.33610999999999], [18.05056, 59.33622999999999], [18.05056, 59.33622999999999], [18.05112, 59.33637], [18.05056, 59.33698], [18.04831, 59.33631], [18.04803, 59.33635], [18.04734, 59.336000000000006], [18.04734, 59.336000000000006], [18.0473, 59.33598], [18.0473, 59.33598], [18.04682, 59.33574000000001]]]}'))),
    ST_GeomFromText(ST_ASTEXT(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[18.05202, 59.33382000000001], [18.05287, 59.3332], [18.05287, 59.3332], [18.0529, 59.33318], [18.05289, 59.33318], [18.05294, 59.33315], [18.05427, 59.333549999999995], [18.05463, 59.3332], [18.05463, 59.3332], [18.05465, 59.33318], [18.05465, 59.33318], [18.05479, 59.33305000000001], [18.05453, 59.33297999999999], [18.0564, 59.33088], [18.05775, 59.33123], [18.0585, 59.3304], [18.0585, 59.3304], [18.05942, 59.32939], [18.06056, 59.32976], [18.06, 59.3304], [18.06, 59.3304], [18.05811, 59.33253], [18.05752, 59.33318], [18.05752, 59.33318], [18.05751, 59.33319], [18.0583, 59.333400000000005], [18.05897, 59.33356], [18.06011, 59.33388000000001], [18.0615, 59.33424999999999], [18.06129, 59.33448], [18.06051, 59.33427], [18.05736, 59.33347], [18.05697, 59.33380999999999], [18.05667, 59.33373], [18.05657, 59.33382000000001], [18.05665, 59.33385], [18.0559, 59.33466], [18.05444, 59.33432], [18.05431, 59.33449], [18.05577, 59.33485], [18.05554, 59.3351], [18.05403, 59.33475], [18.05202, 59.33382000000001]]]}')))
);
```

The error seems to be gone.

This might be the effect of rounding which I did see somewhere on the internet, but unfortunately did not store the link

Comment: Interesting!

When adding ST_GeomFromText(ST_ASTEXT(......))

It will turn the geometry SRID from 4326 to 0.

If forcing it to 4326 it will break again:
ST_GeomFromText(ST_ASTEXT(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(...)), 4326).

But you helped me forward on this :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Luuks answer I ended up with this solution:

[image]

I convert the geometry to SRID 0. Then I can exclude everything that will result in a Linestring or Multilinestring after Intersecting.